# list does not provide a subscript operator

Tags: c++, list

In C++ I got this error:

```
main.cpp:34:15: error: type 'list<std::string>' (aka 'list<basic_string<char>>') does not provide a subscript operator
  cout << code[0];
          ~~~~^~
1 error generated.
make: *** [<builtin>: main.o] Error 1
```

Why? I thought square brackets were meant to get the data of an item of an list by index.

(`code` is an list)

Comment: Please show the definition of `code`.

Comment: {"Aa","Ab","Ac","Ad","Ae","Af"}

Comment: list<string> code;

Comment: @P `aka 'list<basic_string<char>>'`

Comment: I'm new to C++, what is a definition? :P

Comment: A list is not an array

Comment: @273K Indeed, I'm trying to show the OP how to understand the error.

Comment: The website I got the code snippet from told me its an array

Comment: The list<string> code;

Comment: If a website says that a std::list is the same as an array then stop using the website, it's rubbish.

Comment: In C++, `std::list` is (usually) a linked list. It cannot be accessed using an index. If you're looking for a "dynamic array", then use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: @Anpang -- C++ is not Python or any other language you know that use the term "list" to mean an array of items.  A `std::list` is a linked list, and by practice, the linked list data structure has no way of directly accessing the elements without traversing to that element.

Comment: I got it. Just need to turn list to vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **list does not provide a subscript operator**

That's correct, `std::list` does not provide `operator[]`. (`std::vector` and `std::array` both do so.)

It would have been possible for `std::list` to provide an indexing operator, so that `lst[10]` gives you the 10th (counting from 0) element of the list. But the operation would be O(N), so that `lst[100]` would take about 10 times as long as `lst[10]`, because it would have to traverse the list from the beginning to find the requested element. It would allow you to write code that's very inefficient while hiding the inefficiency.

If you're going to need indexing, use a `std::vector`, `std::array`, or something similar.

The C++ standard library provides an indexing operator only when the element can be accessed directly, without traversing the container.